# Displaying the date chosen in Date-Field

Tags: extjs

I'm trying to alert the date of the chosen date in datefield. but i'm

```
getting NaN. any help?

xtype : 'datefield',
            id: 'date_from',
            format: 'd/m/Y',
            editable: false,
            listeners: {
            select: {
                fn:function(a,b,c){
               var date = a-b-c;
                   alert(date);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Why did you use `a - b - c`?

Answer (score 0):

Select's parameters return as 'datefield', value and options. So you cant use it like that: Check api : http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Date-event-select

Working fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/11b9

And code:

```
{
                xtype: 'datefield',
                format: 'd/m/Y',
                editable: false,
                listeners: {
                    select: {
                        fn:function(field, value, eOpts){
                           alert( Ext.Date.format(value,'d/m/Y'));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```